Chartjs afterDraw not showing the line
I am trying to make a chartjs bar chart using dates.
Those are the options i am using to set my chart as i want but i want to add a line at the current date. Here's how i approached it:
public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    indexAxis: 'y',
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
        min: new Date(
          this.todayDate.getFullYear() - 1,
          this.todayDate.getMonth() - 6,
          this.todayDate.getDate()
        ).getTime(),
        time: {
          unit: 'day',
        },
      },
      y: {
        grid: {
          display: false,
        },
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      annotation: {
        annotations: {
          todayLine: {
            drawTime: 'afterDraw',
            type: 'line',
            display: () => true,
            afterDraw: (context) => {
              console.log('Called'); // Log message to check if the function is called

              const {
                ctx,
                chartArea: { top, bottom },
                scales: { x },
              } = context.chart;
              ctx.save();

              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.lineWidth = 3;
              const xValue = x.getPixelForValue(new Date().getTime());
              ctx.moveTo(xValue, top);
              ctx.lineTo(xValue, bottom);
              ctx.stroke();
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };

the problem is even the console.log is not working. What am I doing wrong ?

can you share the rest of the source the component where you wanted to use this chart

There's no afterDraw callback as an option for an item (e.g., line) in chartjs-plugin-annotation. You either use the plugin and define the annotation in its options see fiddle example or make your own plugin with its own afterDraw method, then you don't need chartjs-plugin-annotation, see equivalent example.
